# Java Play 2 - Compile error -> Heroku

Tags: java, deployment, heroku, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku , but I always get the same error msg and I don't know how to fix it.

I made some google searches without any success. I also tried to change the version of sbt. It also runs perfecly fine with

```
play run
```

I am using Play 2.0.2.

Any solutions?

```
[info] Loading project definition from /tmp/build
     [warn]   module not found: play#sbt-plugin;2.0
     [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
     [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-re
    .9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
     [warn] ==== local: tried
     [warn]   /tmp/build_2gxtp2n2ct352/.sbt_home/.ivy2
    .9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
     [warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
     [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releas
    3/2.0/sbt-plugin-2.0.pom
     [warn] ==== heroku-sbt-typesafe: tried
     [warn] ==== heroku-central: tried
     [warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-centr
    3/2.0/sbt-plugin-2.0.pom
     [warn] ==== typesafe: tried
     [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/p
    0/sbt-plugin-2.0.pom
     [warn] ==== heroku-sbt-typesafe: tried
     [warn] ==== heroku-central: tried
     [warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-centr
    3/2.0/sbt-plugin-2.0.pom
     [warn] ==== typesafe: tried
     [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/p
    0/sbt-plugin-2.0.pom
     [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     [warn]   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES
     [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     [warn]   :: play#sbt-plugin;2.0: not found
     [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     [warn]
     [warn]   Note: Some unresolved dependencies have
    these dependencies exist with the requested attrib
     [warn]           play:sbt-plugin:2.0 (sbtVersion=

     [warn]
     [error] {file:/tmp/build_2gxtp2n2ct352/project/}d
    solveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-pl
     Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast,
    build app with sbt
     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.0

    @heroku.com:pure-chamber-6292.git
    mote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook
     failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:pure-
```

Comment: doesn't heroku has a user forum ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the version number of the `sbt-plugin` is wrong.  Make sure that your `project/plugins.sbt` file contains:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.2")
```

Comment: I'm trying to build the play-2.0-spring-module from source and also getting `play#sbt-plugin;x.x: not found`. I've tried 2.0.2, 2.0 (as mentioned here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Build), 2.0.1 (as mentioned here https://github.com/oscarrenalias/play-2.0-spring-module/commit/9134eb5603c2507a9e7de3950999de0621997f0b). I don't see any of these versions when I browse here: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/releases/play/sbt-plugin/. I'm pretty familiar with maven, but not at all with sbt, I must be missing something small, any ideas?

Comment: Ahh, now I see sbt-plugin version 2.0.2 (and other versions) listed under scala version 2.9.1. My sbt shows that it's using scala 2.9.2 so I'm guessing that has something to do with it...

Comment: The Play 2.0.x builds should all use Scala 2.9.1.  Did you do something to switch it to 2.9.2?

Comment: I cloned the play-2.0-spring-module and trying to build it using `sbt package`. So, sbt is finding scala 2.9.2 from somewhere and that must be the issue. I'll try and force it to use 2.9.1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah. I thought you were trying to build a Play app.  You can force the Scala version by adding `scalaVersion := "2.9.1"` to the build settings.