# Error when deploying play 2.2.0 app to heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to deploy java computer-database example from play 2.2.0 framework. The steps I do in the root of the project:

1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "init"
4. heroku create
5. git push heroku master

After the step 5 the app is deployed to heroku and tries to start, but fails with unclear java.lang.NullPointerException. Here are the last few lines of build log:

```
[SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4!jansi.jar (363ms)

:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala

confs: [default]

5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24390kB/38ms)

[warn] The global sbt directory is now versioned and is located at /tmp/build_77392410-f294-4b8e-bce9-b1fab69ca175/.sbt_home/.sbt/0.13.

[warn]   You are seeing this warning because there is global configuration in /tmp/build_77392410-f294-4b8e-bce9-b1fab69ca175/.sbt_home/.sbt but not in /tmp/build_77392410-f294-4b8e-bce9-b1fab69ca175/.sbt_home/.sbt/0.13.

[warn]   The global sbt directory may be changed via the sbt.global.base system property.

[error] java.lang.NullPointerException

[error] Use 'last' for the full log.

Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?  !     Failed to build app with sbt

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x - Java app

To git@heroku.com:nameless-ravine-2560.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:nameless-ravine-2560.git'
```

Then I tried the same with play 2.1.2 and got another error:

```
           [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tmp/build_a41bb3e2-97a2-4da4-b4ad-7ccefadfa094/.sbt_home/.sbt/plugins/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
       [info] Loading project definition from /tmp/build_a41bb3e2-97a2-4da4-b4ad-7ccefadfa094/project
       [warn]   module not found: play#sbt-plugin;2.0
       [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
       [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
       [warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
       [warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
       [warn] ==== local: tried
       [warn]   /tmp/build_a41bb3e2-97a2-4da4-b4ad-7ccefadfa094/.sbt_home/.ivy2/local/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
       [warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
       [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.2_0.12/2.0/sbt-plugin-2.0.pom
       [warn] ==== heroku-sbt-typesafe: tried
       [warn] ==== heroku-central: tried
       [warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.2_0.12/2.0/sbt-plugin-2.0.pom
       [warn] ==== typesafe: tried
       [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.2_0.12/2.0/sbt-plugin-2.0.pom
       [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
       [warn]   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
       [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
       [warn]   :: play#sbt-plugin;2.0: not found
       [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
       [warn]
       [warn]   Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
       [warn]           play:sbt-plugin:2.0 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
       [warn]
       sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.0: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:214)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:102)
        at sbt.IvySbt.liftedTree1$1(Ivy.scala:49)
        at sbt.IvySbt.action$1(Ivy.scala:49)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:58)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:99)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:95)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:114)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:951)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:949)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:972)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:970)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:974)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:969)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:977)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:856)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:853)
        at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
        at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
        at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
        at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
       [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.0: not found
       Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?  !     Failed to build app with sbt

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x - Java app

To git@heroku.com:obscure-cove-6170.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:obscure-cove-6170.git'
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution here [Java Play 2 - Compile error -> Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906682/java-play-2-compile-error-heroku)

I have put

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

instead of the default

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % System.getProperty("play.version"))
```

Though there's now another runtime error, but it's another story...

Comment: For the latest version of play (2.2.2) you should change addSbtPlugin line to this: addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2")